# AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'models' when using tf.keras.models.Sequential() for Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and am trying to follow along this example for Siamese NN with Triplet Loss: https://github.com/13muskanp/Siamese-Network-with-Triplet-Loss/blob/master/Siamese%20Network%20with%20Triplet%20Loss.ipynb

But when I try to run the colab myself, I can't get the Sequential() part to work:
[image]

I've tried everything from using `tf.keras.Sequential()` to modifying the imports but I can't figure out how to make this compile. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: After trying `from tensorflow import keras` I get a different error `AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'models'` [image]

but I can't figure out how to get past this

[image]

Edit 2: showing output of `pip list`

[image]

[image]

Comment: try `from tensorflow import keras`

Comment: @Innat I get `AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'models'` now instead. I added some screenshots showing my output

Comment: first check `pip list` to see if you have mix up the standalone keras or tensorflow.keras. I would suggest to run your code in colab.

Comment: @Innat I edited my post to include the `pip list` results. I have keras version `2.9.0` and tensorflow version `2.15.0`. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Run your code in google colab. See how it goes. This way, your debugging time would be reduced to half.

Comment: @Innat it compiles in Google Colab! Not sure why but thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

please check the Tensorflow version.

Comment: I checked in the screenshot and it's 2.9.1. Do I need something more recent?